# Jquery - Outline top element while hovering

Tags: jquery, hover, element

I'm trying to outline the top element being hovered.

```
    $(function()
    {
      var ElementSelector = null;
      var SelectedElement = null;

      $("*:not(div#ElementSelector)").hover
      (
        function()
        {
          SelectedElement = ($(this).length > 1 ? $(this).find("*:last") : $(this));
          if(ElementSelector != null)
          {
            ElementSelector.css("width", SelectedElement.width()).css("height", SelectedElement.height())
              .css("left", SelectedElement.offset().left).css("top", SelectedElement.offset().top)
              .css("marginTop", SelectedElement.css("marginTop")).css("marginLeft", SelectedElement.css("marginLeft"))
              .css("marginRight", SelectedElement.css("marginRight")).css("marginBottom", SelectedElement.css("marginBottom"))
              .css("paddingLeft", SelectedElement.css("paddingLeft")).css("paddingTop", SelectedElement.css("paddingTop"))
              .css("paddingRight", SelectedElement.css("paddingRight")).css("paddingBottom", SelectedElement.css("paddingBottom"));
          }

          SelectedElement.click(function()
          {
            SelectedElement.css("background-color", "green");
          });
        }, 
        function ()
        {
          SelectedElement.unbind("click");
        }
      );

      $("body").append("<div id='ElementSelector' style='width:0px;height:0px;z-index: 100000;position:absolute;border: 2px solid red;padding:0px;margin:0px;margin:0px;'></div>");
      ElementSelector = $("div#ElementSelector");
    });
```

This is what I've come up with so far.. But it bugs a lot! So any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by 'it bugs a lot'? Does the above code work? Could you try to post a sample on jsbin.com ?

Comment: Can you clarify. What does 'it bugs a lot' mean?

Comment: Sorry for not being too clear about "what bugs". We'll, the selector selects, but, sometimes it kind of get's stuck. And other times the dimensions don't add up.. You can see it in action here: http://jsbin.com/arexi/

Comment: I have recently a strong feeling, what people unwilling to debug theirs code hope it be done by some one else just after they will copy past it here.

Comment: Come on, that's just low. I have not just copy pasted code. I have asked for someone else to look at it. Since I've Googled, debugged, tested and stared my eyes at it for several hours without finding anything. Forums like this is often my last alternative. I'm not hoping for some cheap code, im hoping for someone to say, hey, you've just missed this. Or "this". Or, that's not the way to calculate the correct dimensions, use this method instead. That's what im after. So please, save you breath for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of specifying all the styles in your code why not use CSS and jQuery's addClass, removeClass, and toggleClass functions? This should clean up your code quite a bit and put the presentation where it belongs - in the style sheets.

Comment: Since this is just a test I have ignored layer separation. This will of course be cleaned up later on.

Comment: I figured by "bugs a lot" you meant that the code was messy and you wanted to know how to clean it up.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use [.hover](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover#overout)?

I would heavily suggest cleaning up your code and doing what Mark said and putting the style within the style sheets. It only makes sense when working with jQuery, it can get to be quite a mess.

If you would have done it the right way the first time around, testing your code would be much easier and you would have a much better base to start from, in fact your 'test' would probably become the end product.

The whole append thing doesn't make any sense, why don't you set it using [jQuery's CSS functions](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS)? That's what they're there for.